# Spring boot deployed on Tomcat 8 having structure or application context issues

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a simple spring boot application which I am able to run in my local with the url http://localhost:8080/#/appName. This is my application structure

[image]

When I package this as a war and try to deploy this in the linux server, I am not able to load the application with the same context ( http://SERVERNAME:PORT/#/appName) that I was able to load in my local. I think I am missing something, can someone guide me.

Here is the application structure after deployed in the tomcat server.

[image]

Under the WEB-INF/classes/ directory, the content is as below.

[image]

Comment: Were you using the embedded container when you say "run in local"? Or was it a local tomcat installation?
If you are not using the embedded container, then the application context is handled by the container and not by the application. In tomcat by default it is the war name. 
If you are running the spring boot app within embedded container you can specify the context in your application.properties file with "server.context-path"

Comment: I mean it works in the embedded container. Later I created the war and tried deploying it in the remote Tomcat server. It deployed with the different directory structure as mentioned in my post. Thats where I am held up, not sure how to hit the application

Comment: I just changed only the main class to extend SpringBootServletInitializer and packaged it as war before I deployed it to Tomcat instance as abc.war. Then later I am trying to hit with http://server:port/#/abc as I used to access the same in my local as http://localhost:8080/#/abc

FYI, I included the dependency spring-boot-starter-tomcat as provided in pom.xml

Answer (score 2):

Spring boot when deployed into a tomcat container will have its context root as its war name by default. Lets say you have tomcat installation at "localhost" on port 8080. You deploy the war named "abc.war", which means you drop it into the webapps directory. The app gets deployed with the main folder being "abc" and other folders (WEB-INF,META-INF,etc) within it. You context root of that particular application will now be

> http://localhost:8080/abc

If your application has an endpoint path as "cde/fg", then with the context root added to this path, the entire url will be

> http://localhost:8080/abc/cde/fg

**But**, if you are running the **exact same** spring boot app in an embedded container running on "localhost" on port 8080, (and assuming the application.properties did not mention a server.context-path in it), then the above end point in the embedded container will be

> http://localhost:8080/cde/fg

The application is then deployed in the root context of the container.

I assume this subtle difference is what you are missing. If my guess is right, after you deploy in the tomcat container simply add the war name to the url like this -

> http://SERVERNAME:PORT/{warname}/#/appName

Comment: I am completely with you on this and I have done the same.

When I run the app in my local with the embedded container, I run it with the URL http://localhost:8080/#/abc

In the remote Tomcat instance, the war I deployed is abc.war and my routing is controlled by AngularJS. So with that, I am accessing the application with the URL http://server:8081/abc/#/abc

FYI, My spring controller is annotated with @RestController

Comment: Can anyone throw some lights here?

Comment: I think its not identifying the index.html located in the resources/static/index.html. Is it the correct place for index.html or should I place it somewhere else. I tried placing this under /WEB-INF/classes but still didnt work.

As per my expectation, the index.html should load by default and other routes will be added by Angular based on the navigation

Comment: If someone is facing a similar issue, then here is what I did to make it work. I am not sure if this is the correct approach but it worked.

I had to create a directory 'webapp' inside 'src/main/' and moved all my static contents inside this directory. Then later accessed my application through http://servername:port/{{warname}}/{{endpoint}}. It worked

Comment: Did you come across [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)?

Comment: Yes I did it. Infact I used this as my reference but only the change in directory structure helped me